# MongoDB geospatial: how to find if a point is within range from any other point

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I'm struggling with completing this query but maybe I'm using the wrong approach. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
db.cells.find(
   {
     loc: {
        $nearSphere: {
           $geometry: {
              type : "Point",
              coordinates : [ 31.0, 31.0 ]
           },
           $minDistance: 0,
           $maxDistance: $range
        }
     }
   }
)
```

Here `$range` should be a field of my document but in a previous answer they told me that there is no option to do that in MongoDB.

So I would like to retrieve all the documents where the field `loc` is a point within distance inferior to field `range`. Is it possible to do it with a single query? I can restructure the document format if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

No it is not possible. Range criteria has to be know at query creation time.